# Jmeter V5.6.3 HTML report -> Statistics under total showing half count of samples and fail count. Which is the right count of samples and failures?

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aniw8.png)

Here in statistics under row total -> samples count is 2600 and fails 251 . However in distribution count for each label , if we sum samples count is 5200 and failures is 502. Which is right value and why is the discrepancy? Test plan ahs API calls only, each thread is 1 API call and wrapped in transaction controller.

why is the discrepancy? Test plan ahs API calls only, each thread is 1 API call and wrapped in transaction controller

Comment: Any suggestion anyone?

Comment: better to put that image as text to increase the visibility

Answer (score 0):

I have one "suggestion above". The "discrepancy" is "because" **you** caused it, most probably you have filtered out some transactions so they don't appear in the Total statistics.

Example situation: there is a test plan with 4 Samplers: 2 successful and 2 failing (represented by [Dummy Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dummy-sampler))

[image]

and let's imagine the situation I run the test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and for some reason I don't include `Failing Sampler 2` into the report:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter="^(Failing Sampler 1|Successful Sampler 1|Successful Sampler 2)(-success|-failure)?$" -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
```

In this case I will get the following Dashboard:

[image]

As you can see in "Total" I have 4 samplers however there are only 3 entries, the same for "Fail", in the top of the table there are 2 failed transactions however there is only one row with the failed one.

See [Reporting configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting) for more details